# Why does Tensorboard shows a single value as many in the histogram visualization?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was trying to visualize the output of all the activation functions in each layers of my fully-connected network and I was surprised when I checked the last layer. It is a very simple regression model and the output layer has therefore one neuron. I know it would be better to visualize it as a scalar, but I was just trying to visualize it using histograms and I realized that the value is somehow split. Does this make any sense? I would rather expect that it cannot be visualized at all or that the histogram would consist of a single point.

[image: Histogram visualization]

Comment: Maybe each of those histograms corresponds to a single batch, so you actually have multiple values at each step?

Comment: Are steps count in the vertical axis is actual train step value?

Comment: @pkubik For this particular plot (printed in the validation) I only used one sample (so, batch size = 1).

Comment: @Sharky yes, those are the steps, and for each step there is only one value recorded.

Comment: could you please show  model code